# String Interpolation In Codesmith Generator

Tags: codesmith

Is there a way to use some of the newer c# features like string interpolation, ie:
var string = $"Hello {worldVar}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codesmith got back to me and indicated this will be in the next version when they bump their internal runtime from 4.0 to 4.7.

Answer (score 0):

I work at CodeSmith Tools, the latest version (8.0) added support for .NET 4.7 and string interpolation.